# Significato di "stare a lui come lui stava alla generalità dei mortali"

Tags: meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Ferro* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Nelle mezze stagioni il regno di Sandro erano le palestre di roccia. Ce ne sono diverse, a due o tre ore di bicicletta da Torino, e sarei curioso di sapere se sono tuttora frequentate: i Picchi del Pagliaio con il Torrione Wolkmann, i Denti di Cumiana, Roca Patanüa (significa Roccia Nuda), il Plô, lo Sbarüa, ed altri, dai nomi casalinghi e modesti. Quest’ultimo, lo Sbarüa, mi pare fosse stato scoperto da Sandro stesso, o da un suo mitico fratello, che Sandro non mi fece mai vedere, ma che, dai suoi scarsi accenni, doveva **stare a lui come lui stava alla generalità dei mortali**.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "stare a lui come lui stava alla generalità dei mortali" che appare nell'ultima frase di questo brano. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Ho cercato alla [voce "stare" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stare), ma ci sono tantissime accezioni, che non riesco a vedere a quale possa corrispondere l'uso che si fa di questo verbo nel testo citato. Cosa vuol dire che il fratello di Sandro stava a Sandro come Sandro stava alla generalità dei mortali?

Aggiungo per dare un po' più di contesto, l'unico altro passaggio del racconto in cui si fa riferimento al fratello di Sandro:

> lo Sbarüa è un prisma di granito che sporge di un centinaio di metri da una modesta collina irta di rovi e di bosco ceduo: come il Veglio di Creta, è spaccato dalla base alla cima da una fenditura che si fa salendo via via piú stretta, fino a costringere lo scalatore ad uscire in parete, dove, appunto, si spaura, e dove esisteva allora un singolo chiodo, lasciato caritatevolmente dal fratello di Sandro.

Sandro è descritto nel racconto come una persona che aveva una grande dimestichezza con la montagna e, in particolare, come un scalatore molto abile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prendendo la definizione del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stare/) il significato in questo caso è quello *"matematico"* di *"essere in rapporto a"*:

> b. In matematica, *stare a*, essere in dato rapporto: *4 sta a 2 come 6 sta a 3*, il rapporto di 4 a 2 è uguale al rapporto di 6 a 3, e così via.

ovvero il significato è di **effettuare un paragone** (in questo caso tra due persone):

Nel brano il narratore dice che Sandro racconta poco riguardo al fratello, ma da quel poco si deduce che i due non si somigliano per niente (il paragone tra Sandro e il fratello sembra essere lo stesso che si può fare tra Sandro e il resto dell'umanità).

Un'altra interpretazione - suggerita da @DaG - è che questa "proporzione" tra i fratelli riguardi nello specifico le loro abilità di rocciatori, ovvero il fratello di Sandro era tanto più abile di Sandro stesso, quando Sandro era tanto più abile del resto delle persone.

Schematicamente:

Fratello : Sandro = Sandro : La maggior parte delle persone

Questo uso figurato o esteso di "stare a" al di fuori dello stretto ambito della matematica è assai diffuso.

Comment: Mi hai preceduto! :) Sicuramente sta descrivendo una proporzione (fratello : Sandro = Sandro : mortali), ma non credo che il senso sia che non si somigliano. Non ho presente il contesto, ma sospetto che Sandro fosse un rocciatore molto più abile dei comuni mortali, o qualcosa del genere, e che suo fratello fosse ancora di gran lunga più abile di lui. Può essere, @Charo?

Comment: @DaG è possibile che il senso sia quello che stai descrivendo, non ci avevo pensato.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Questo rapporto di cui parla il Treccani mi sembra (dagli esempi riportati) che sia un rapporto di proporzionalità e non riesco a capire cosa possa avere a che vedere col rapporto tra due persone.

Comment: È un uso figurato, @Charo, anche abbastanza frequente. È come se quantificassimo le abilità (o altre qualità) delle persone e costruissimo una proporzione. Levi aveva per giunta una formazione scientifica, ma non lo usa solo lui.

Comment: Pescando a caso dalla rete con «"sta a * come * sta a" -matematica -proporzioni»: “La bellezza dei ragazzi sta a quella delle ragazze come la pittura a olio sta a quella a pastello” o “Il teatro sta a Pirandello come la tela sta a Fontana”...

Comment: Ha perfettamente senso quello che hai detto nel primo commento, @DaG. Gli unici riferimenti al fratello che appaiono nel racconto sono questo "***mitico*** fratello" e poi un po' più avanti "lo Sbarüa è un prisma di granito che [...] è spaccato dalla base alla cima da una fenditura che si fa salendo via via piú stretta, fino a costringere lo scalatore ad uscire in parete, dove, appunto, si spaura, e dove esisteva allora un singolo chiodo, lasciato caritatevolmente dal fratello di Sandro".

Comment: Sono d'accordo con l'interpretazione che ha fatto @DaG nel suo primo commento. Quindi, potresti modificare la risposta, per favore?

Comment: @DaG per quanto riguarda il tuo commento 5 sono d'accordo col primo esempio, ma meno col secondo. "“Il teatro sta a Pirandello come la tela sta a Fontana” secondo me in questo caso "stare" significa più "appartenere".

Comment: Veramente neanch'io, come @DaG, credo che il senso sia che non si somigliano. In tutto il racconto si vede come Sandro ha un rapporto di grande familiarità con la montagna e, in particolare, è uno scalatore molto abile. Ma il fratello è qualificato come "mitico" e non ha neanche bisogno di quel singolo chiodo (che infatti ha lasciato lui caritatevolemente, pensando agli altri) per superare quella difficile parete.

Comment: Quindi, adesso mi sembra molto chiaro che il paragone sia tra le abilità in relazione alla montagna del fratello rispetto a Sandro e di Sandro rispetto la maggioranza delle persone ("i comuni mortali").

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Può darsi, anche se non sono sicuro di vedere la differenza fra i due esempi che avevo colto a caso. Mi sembrano istanze di una costruzione molto diffusa, a mo' di battuta, di gioco enigmistico, di ragionamento conciso. Trovo per esempio “TG1 sta a Verità come Platinette sta a Femminilità” o, in una rubrica di Bartezzaghi: “in inglese [...] troviamo una parola che sta a sensuosità come un fiume maestoso sta a un affluente minore: sensuousness” (https://www.repubblica.it/rubriche/lessicoenuvole/2010/05/31/news/antologia_l_n_ultima-4444714/).